# BASH: copy only images from directory, not copying folder structure and rename copied files in sequential order

Tags: bash, terminal

I have found an old HDD which was used in the family computer back in 2011. There are a lot of images on it which I would love to copy to my computer and print out in a nice photobook as a surprise to my parents and sister.

However, I have a problem: These photos have been taken with older cameras. Which means that I have a lot of photos with names such as: 01, 02, etc. These are now in hunderds of sub-folders.

I have already tried the following command but I still get exceptions where the file cannot be copied because one with the same name already exists.

Example: `cp: cannot create regular file 'C:/Users/patri/Desktop/Fotoboek/battery.jpg': File exists`

The command I execute:

`$ find . -type f -regex '.*\(jpg\|jpeg\|png\|gif\|bmp\|mp4\)' -exec cp --backup=numbered '{}' C:/Users/patri/Desktop/Fotoboek \;`

I had hoped that the `--backup=numbered` would solve my problem. (I thought that it would add either a 0,1,2 etc to the filename if it already exists, which it unfortunately doesn't do successfully).

Is there a way to find only media files such as images and videos like I have above and make it so that every file copied gets renamed to a sequential number? So the first copied image would have the name 0, then the 2nd 1, etc.

Comment: _I still get exceptions_ : How do the exceptions manifest themselves?

Comment: I still get exceptions with the description saying that the file cannot be created because it already exists, @user1934428 such as: `cp: cannot create regular file 'C:/Users/patri/Desktop/Fotoboek/battery.jpg': File exists`

Comment: Did you check the permissions? Basically you ask  `cp` to  rename `battery.jpg` into `battery.jpg.~1~` before copying. Try the renaming for this example file manually; does it work?

Comment: BTW, why is this question labelled `cmd`? There is nothing in your question related to Windows and its horrible command shell.

Comment: I do have permission on the destination. However, when I try to rename a file on the source (The HDD) I do get a prompt telling me that I need to provide Admin rights. 

I decided to try and open the terminal as an Administrator but the problem unfortunately still persists. @user1934428

Comment: So this is the problem, and it is unrelated to cp --backup. The prompt is strange; I would not expect this in, i.e., Linux or MacOS, though I have seen something like this under Windows. In any case, this is then a question for [su] and not Stackoverflow.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help in the meantime, I will post the question on the appropriate website and delete it from stackoverflow. Thanks again and have an amazing day @user1934428

Comment: Make sure that you are focusing in your question on **renaming** of the file, since this is the core problem.

Comment: I don't understand how a write permission issue on the source could possibly cause your problem. Are you sure your `cp` command works as expected? Did you try to copy the same file twice by hand (`cp --backup=numbered 'battery.jpg' C:/Users/patri/Desktop/Fotoboek`)? If yes what happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

** *doesn't do successfully* ** is not a clear question.  If I try your `find` command on sample directories on my system (Linux Mint 20), it works just fine.  It creates files with `~1~`, `~2~`, ... added to the filename (mind you after the extension).

If you want a quick and dirty solution, you could do:

```
#!/bin/bash  

counter=1
find sourcedir -type f -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' file
do
    filename=$(basename -- "$file")
    extension="${filename##*.}"
    fileonly="${filename%.*}"
    cp "$file" "targetdir/${fileonly}_${counter}.$extension"
    (( counter += 1 ))
done
```

- In this solution the counter is incremented every time a file is copied.  The numbers are not sequential for each filename.
- Yes I know it is an anti-pattern, and not ideal but it works.

---

If you want a "more evolved" version of the previous, where the numbers are sequential, you could do:

```
#!/bin/bash

find sourcedir -type f -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' file
do
    filename=$(basename -- "$file")
    extension="${filename##*.}"
    fileonly="${filename%.*}"
    counter=1
    while [[ -f "targetdir/${fileonly}_${counter}.$extension" ]]
    do
        (( counter += 1 ))
    done
    cp "$file" "targetdir/${fileonly}_${counter}.$extension"

done
```

- This version increments the counter every time a file is found to exist with that counter.  Ex. if you have 3 a.jpg files, they will be named a_1.jpg, a_2.jpg, a_3.jpg

Comment: Instead of a counter you have the option to automatically name the destination with the help of `mktemp` which knows how to prevent collision `dest=$(mktemp -u -p targetdir/ -t "${fileonly}_XXXX.$extension")`